# Cloudera edge node not in Azure RM template. Why?

Tags: azure, cloudera

Cloudera documentation [talks about](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_sg_gateway_setup.html) (and, I believe, recommends) use of an edge node (aka gateway node) as a means of controlling external access to the cluster. 
I have recently deployed a Cloudera cluster on Azure using the [provided ARM template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/cloudera-on-centos/azuredeploy.json) and discovered that no edge node gets provisioned during the deployment. Why is that? If an edge node is recommended should that not be included in such a deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually right now every node provisioned using this Cloudera ARM template is an edge node (has the gateway role). This is a simple configuration for smaller clusters. You can customize the template to provision dedicated edge nodes as needed.

Comment: Ah, so the "gateway" is the edge node? Got it, obvious really :) Thanks Paige.

Comment: Quick follow-up question if I may. I looked at the cluster I've spun up and each node has "HDFS Gateway", "Hive Gateway", "Spark Gateway", "YARN Gateway". Do any of these "gateways" specifically designate a node as an edge node, or are they just different gateways that people typically choose to put onto a single "edge node"? Hope that makes sense.